# Combine filter results in for loop

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django to make a website. I want to combine multiple filter results (Querysets).

My models' relationship

'Staff' 1:m 'Member' 1:m  'PaymentHistory' 1:1 'RefundHistory'

My view.py:

```
wanted_refund = set()
for m in staff.members.all():
    payment = m.PaymentHistory.filter(division="Membership")
    for p in payment:
        try:
            refund = RefundHistory.objects.filter(payment=p).filter(refund_date__range=[this_month_start, date])

            wanted_refund.add(refund)
        except RefundHistory.DoesNotExist:
            pass
 context = {
             'wanted_refund' : wanted_refund,}
    return render(request, 'refund.html', context)
```

But, it doesn't work by using filters. It only works when I use 'get'.

`print(refund)` shows me the result like this:

```
 < QuerySet [] >

 < QuerySet [] >

 < QuerySet [] >

 < QuerySet [< RefundHistory: RefundHistory object >] >
```

I want to use only the Querysets that have the object and what I want is the below one in template:

```
{% for refund in wanted_history %}
 {{ refund.refund_date }}
 {{ refund.refund_amount}}
 {% endfor %}
```

How do I pass over the multiple filters results in for loop?

Comment: Are you wanting to have the result of that filter joined for every payment? As in, get the refund range for every payment in one queryset?

Comment: I want to have the existed RefundHistory object for every payment. I edited my post. How I get the results in one queryset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could join querysets using pipe operator:

```
wanted_refund = RefundHistory.objects.none()
for m in staff.members.all():
    payment = m.PaymentHistory.filter(division="Membership")
    for p in payment:
        try:
            wanted_refund |= RefundHistory.objects.filter(payment=p).filter(refund_date__range=[this_month_start, date])
        except RefundHistory.DoesNotExist:
            pass
wanted_refund = wanted_refund.distinct()
context = {'wanted_refund': wanted_refund}
return render(request, 'refund.html', context)
```

Also, if it will work for you, you may just use `wanted_refund.update(list(refund))` in place of `wanted_refund.add(refund)`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get the refund history for every payment of every member using a single query of the `RefundHistory`:

```
payments = []
for m in staff.members.all():
    payments.extend(m.PaymentHistory.filter(division="Membership").values_list('pk', flat=True))

wanted_refund = RefundHistory.objects.filter(payment__pk__in=payments, refund_date__range=[this_month_start, date])

context = {'wanted_refund' : wanted_refund,}
return render(request, 'refund.html', context)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! What does '__pk__in' and 'flat=True' mean?

Comment: Ok so the `__pk` means that we want to match on the `pk` field of the payment. The `__in` means that we want to match anything that is in the list that we create using `payment.values_list('pk', flat=True)`. So for the payment with `pk=2` it might check if 2 is in `[2, 3, 4]` for example. Now the `flat=True` argument to `.values_list` forces the list to be of the form `[pk, pk, pk]` rather than `[(pk), (pk), (pk)]` since if we provided extra fields, `.values_list` returns a list of tuples. Some more examples are [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

Comment: Thanks! But, it only has one query set when the query set is more than two.

Comment: Could you explain more about what you mean when you say "the query set is more than two" please?

Comment: How's that edit? The solution should now get append all the member pks so we get results for all members